# Remove only the blanks in front of the qualitative values of a dataset?

Tags: r, stringr

I have a dataset in R with several columns. Some of them contain qualitative values, whose first character is a blank space. I would like to know how I can remove only the blanks in front of the qualitative value. For example, " Living room" should be "Living room". I have thought about implementing the str_replace function and include the pattern that allows to do it, however, I need to perform this procedure in several columns of the dataset.

Any better idea?

```
str_replace(df$column, *pattern*)
```

Comment: Try `stringr::str_remove(df$column, "^\\s")

Comment: `trimws()` is a nice base function that trims whitespace from both the beginning and end of strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `trims()` across multiple variables (i.e., columns) of your data frame using `mutate()` and `across()` from the `dplyr` package. First, here's some toy data:

```r
df <- data.frame(
  id = c(1,2, 3),
  var1 = c(" Living Room", " Kitchen", " Great Room"),
  var2 = c(" Guest Room", " Master Bedrom", " Bathroom"),
  var3 = c(" Office", " Laundry Room", " Casita")
)

df %>% glimpse()
```

**Output:**

```
Rows: 3
Columns: 4
$ id   <dbl> 1, 2, 3
$ var1 <chr> " Living Room", " Kitchen", " Great Room"
$ var2 <chr> " Guest Room", " Master Bedrom", " Bathroom"
$ var3 <chr> " Office", " Laundry Room", " Casita"
```

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>% 
  mutate(
    across(starts_with("var"), trimws)
  ) 

df %>% glimpse()
```

**Output:**

```
Rows: 3
Columns: 4
$ id   <dbl> 1, 2, 3
$ var1 <chr> "Living Room", "Kitchen", "Great Room"
$ var2 <chr> "Guest Room", "Master Bedrom", "Bathroom"
$ var3 <chr> "Office", "Laundry Room", "Casita"
```